# VBA does not see .pdf files

Tags: excel, vba, directory, zip

This code is not zipping files one after another but a bit random. So I wanted it to follow the record number at the beginning of each .pdf file's name.  Plus added zip files names. It all runs nicely BUT don't see .pdfs. 0 files copied to 1 zip file, as it says.

```
Sub zipfiles2()
Const filesPerZip = 20
Const SourcePath = "given_path"
Dim DestPath As String, srcFolder As Object, destFolder As Object
Dim fso As Object, f As Object, zipcount As Long, n As Long, i As Long
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set srcFolder = fso.GetFolder(SourcePath)
DestPath = SourcePath
zipcount = 1
If Not fso.FolderExists(DestPath & "\Rebate Cash " & zipcount) Then
    fso.CreateFolder DestPath & "\Rebate Cash " & zipcount
End If
Set destFolder = fso.GetFolder(DestPath & "\Rebate Cash " & zipcount)
i = 0
' Copy files into folders
For Each f In srcFolder.files
    If LCase(Right(f.Name, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
        ' Extract record number from the file name
        Dim fileNameParts() As String
        fileNameParts = Split(f.Name, "_")
        
        If UBound(fileNameParts) >= 1 Then
            If IsNumeric(fileNameParts(0)) Then
                recordNumber = CLng(fileNameParts(0))
                
                ' If folder full, create another
                i = i + 1
                If i > filesPerZip Then
                    zipcount = zipcount + 1
                    If Not fso.FolderExists(DestPath & "\Rebate Cash " & zipcount) Then
                        fso.CreateFolder DestPath & "\Rebate Cash " & zipcount
                    End If
                    Set destFolder = fso.GetFolder(DestPath & "\Rebate Cash " & zipcount)
                    i = 1
                End If
                ' Debug.Print f.Name, destFolder.Path
                f.Copy destFolder.Path & "\"
                n = n + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next f ' This is the correct loop closure
   ' Create zip files using shell application
Dim shellApp, zipname
Set shellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For i = 1 To zipcount
    ' Create new zip
    zipname = DestPath & "\Rebate Cash " & i & ".zip"
    Open zipname For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1
    ' Copy files into zip
    shellApp.Namespace(zipname).CopyHere shellApp.Namespace(DestPath & "\Rebate Cash " & i).Items
Next
MsgBox n & " files copied to " & zipcount & " zip files", vbInformation
```

End Sub

Any more help/advises on that?

Comment: Please check your FOR statements - as currently written, STEP will process every 20th occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub zipfiles()

    Const filesPerZip = 20
    Const SourcePath = "C:\temp\SO\pdfs"
   
   ' Initialize variables
    Dim DestPath As String, srcFolder As Object, destFolder As Object
    Dim fso As Object, f As Object, zipcount As Long, n As Long, i As Long
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set srcFolder = fso.GetFolder(SourcePath)
    DestPath = SourcePath
    
    zipcount = 1
    If Not fso.folderexists(DestPath & zipcount) Then
        fso.CreateFolder DestPath & zipcount
    End If
    Set destFolder = fso.GetFolder(DestPath & zipcount)
    
    'copy fies into folders
    For Each f In srcFolder.Files
       If Right(f.Name, 4) = ".pdf" Then
       
           ' if folder full create another
           i = i + 1
           If i > filesPerZip Then
                zipcount = zipcount + 1
                If Not fso.folderexists(DestPath & zipcount) Then
                    fso.CreateFolder DestPath & zipcount
                End If
                Set destFolder = fso.GetFolder(DestPath & zipcount)
                i = 1
            End If
              
            'Debug.Print f.Name, destFolder.Path
            f.Copy destFolder.Path & "\"
            n = n + 1
            
       End If
    Next
    
    'Create zip files using shell application
    Dim shellApp, zipname
    Set shellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    
    For i = 1 To zipcount
    
        ' create new zip see -https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm
        zipname = DestPath & "\" & i & ".zip"
        Open zipname For Output As #1
        Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
        Close #1
    
        ' copy files into zip
        shellApp.Namespace(zipname).CopyHere shellApp.Namespace(SourcePath & i).Items
    Next
    
    MsgBox n & " files copied to " & zipcount & " zip files", vbInformation
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Man, it works perfectly. But is there a way to add a popup window to provide the name for zip files? In general it should be "Name_of_the file + running number"

Comment: @ONY95 Normal way is to use a [InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function)